# Check when transaction was added to the mempool?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-cli

I know how to check when a specific transaction was included in the block. But how do I check when my `bitcoind` node first saw it? I would like to estimate for how long the transaction stayed unconfirmed after it was broadcasted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getrawmempool` interface provides this information in the `time` field, though it is potentially very slow to respond with a large number of transactions in the mempool. It does not record this time once the transaction is removed from the mempool for non-wallet transactions, so it either needs to be gathered from this interface or recorded on addition with the `zmq` socket.

```
"result": {
    "89ee39117b4b55e54ace29c631eef80a875ae109a4fbd79ddd10b6f21329e88d": {
        "size": 225,
        "fee": 0.00000573,
        "modifiedfee": 0.00000573,
        "time": 1556802637,
        "height": 574268,
        "descendantcount": 2,
        "descendantsize": 451,
        "descendantfees": 3247,
        "ancestorcount": 1,
        "ancestorsize": 225,
        "ancestorfees": 573,
        "wtxid": "89ee39117b4b55e54ace29c631eef80a875ae109a4fbd79ddd10b6f21329e88d",
        "depends": [

        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `getmempoolentry` give the same information?

Comment: I assumed they wanted to do bulk analysis.

Comment: Thank you both, these are the useful commands One clarification though: am I right that once the transaction is confirmed and gone from the mempool- there is no way to check when it was first seen?

Comment: Yes, that information is not kept around. In fact, apart from historical blocks (and only when not pruning), nothing at all is kept around about confirmed transactions (in general you can't test whether a particular transaction was confirmed in the past).